# How to find these derivatives of a implicit function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The equation

$x^3 + 2y^3 + z^3 + xyz = 4$

$x,y > 0$ describe a graph of a function: $ z = f(x,y)$.

Find, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$

So I know how to find the first one, you just take the derivative in accordance to x, but I'm confused on how to do the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is probably better notated as follows:

$$\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)$$

In other words, you just find the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$, and then find the partial derivative of *that* with respect to $x$. The notation is a little unintuitive so I can see the confusion.

Comment: okay I see, so would I take the partial in respect to dx after finding the derivative with respect to dy?

Comment: Yup, that's right!

Comment: ugh, I'm still stuck, how would you write this out in terms of the chain rule?